# Pc boots after turning on power supply

Tags: motherboard

My pc boots after turning on the power supply, I can't use my power or reset buttons, the cables should be connected correctly
My power leds do work.
when I click shutdown, windows shuts down, my screen turns black, but my fans keep working, so the pc is not off

Any idea?

mohterboard: amd socket am2 abit nf-m2s
case: raidmax altas

I checked all cables and they are connected correctly, I checked the manual.
Is it possible to insert the pins in the wrong way? The text on it is pointing to the left now.

I got this problem after switching to a new case, everthing worked fine with my old case

Comment: Is your power button jammed in the ON position? Have you forgotten to connect either button, or have you misconnected either one? Or used a jumper across the wrong pins? Double-check those connections.

Comment: @minitech, this should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify that the power and reset cables are correctly attached to the mobo? Maybe one came loose or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

> mohterboard: amd socket am2 abit nf-m2s case: raidmax altas

As other people have said, you might have inserted the connector onto the wrong pins, or have a loose fitting connection.  Download the manual for your motherboard, and triple check that you have the connectors on the right pins.

> Is it possible to insert the pins in the wrong way?

They are switches, which are more or less interrupted pieces of wire.  Just as you can swap the ends of a plain wire and it will still conduct electricity, your switches can also have their ends swapped, and still work perfectly.

> I got this problem after switching to a new case, everthing worked fine with my old case

On newer cases, there is often an intermediate "jumper" between the switches and the connector on the motherboard.  This is there for both safety (in case you quickly pull your case apart and forget to disconnect that) and convenience (so you can leave the bottom part of the wire on the mobo while taking it out).  Double check the entire length of the wire between the switch and the mobo connector, and see that you haven't disconnected such a jumper.

**If all else fails**

First, if you have a way of electrically determining that the switches work (like a logic probe), then I'd go with that.

If your switches are fine, and you are worried you have a defective motherboard, you can actually test out the power and reset switches by shorting them with a *normal* jumper.  This is mostly just an option for the reset switch, as the power switch often has a split/extra pin between its connectors, and a normal jumper would not work.

Simply remove the jumper connectors for the switch, place a standard jumper over the connectors, and plug in/turn on power.

Ideally you'd do this while the computer was turned on, but I *cannot* recommend you do that, as it is dangerous.  Instead, I suggest you do such a test with the computer off to begin with; just like connecting any other jumper.